# CKEditor Readonly with No Toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor on my site and everything seems to work great for the most part.

When a user fills out the editor, it creates a "Post" that is stored in the database and I would then pull it out later on and show it on the page.

On the page that I have posts on, I add the data from the database to a textarea and then enable the CKEditor on it to preserve the formatting that was used.

Since I make this element `disabled`, there is no point in showing the toolbar to the user. The buttons aren't active and you can't make changes from this page.

When rendering the editor, I use:

```
       var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('previousUpdate', {
            removePlugins: 'toolbar',
            width: '100%',
            height: 200,
        });
```

This code however results in not enabling the basic formatting that was used on the posts (Bold, Italic, Bullets, Lists).

Is there a way I can remove the toolbar but still allow it to use the formatting that was done originally (the content would still contain those HTML tags used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never understand why not simply display HTML content without using the editor at all, but maybe I'm missing something.

Anyway, ACF in automatic mode (default mode) works in the way you described it. If Bold feature is not enabled, then `<strong>` tag is stripped off etc. There is a [nice guide about ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) which explains how to set `config.allowedContent` to allow certain tags/attributes/styles/classes.

Comment: Thanks for the info - You have a good point but and I may change it. For the time being, it offers a nice scrollable box with with the formatted text in it (which I know you can do with a div). I guess I just wanted to see if it was possible to do what I need without changing too much

Comment: We use it within a form and therefore I can ensure the user sees exactly the same (consent) which I will save afterwards to db.